# Meaning of "in the dignitaries"

Tags: meaning

What does "in the dignitaries" mean when it's used in sentences like *in the dignitaries of the cathedral* or *in the dignitaries of the nascent counterculture*?

Is my abridged dictionary failing me, as far as the definition of *dignitary*?  Am I wrong in assuming that "in" is a preposition here?

I've encountered this usage in a couple of passages, e.g. in *The Mirror of Parliament*, by John Henry Barrow, page 3523, we read:

> *Thus if there be any vacancies **in the dignitaries** of the cathedral of Canterbury, and another vacancy should occur, we propose that the third vacancy shall be filled up.*

And, again, in [*The Grasshopper King*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CAQaAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=Jordan+Ellenberg+dignitaries+counterculture+%22The+Grasshopper+King%22&source=bl&ots=STldJii19A&sig=uUOVoJq7SWgJDN3ZZiI5oOUMwmg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl4Nbo7cPLAhVK0WMKHY0gCj0Q6AEIRjAF#v=onepage&q=Jordan%20Ellenberg%20dignitaries%20counterculture%20%22The%20Grasshopper%20King%22&f=false), by Jordan Ellenberg, page 47, we read:

> *Eight months before, my parents had moved from New York, where they had operated a restaurant by the same name ["the Grape Arbor Café and Grill"] which enjoyed much traffic **in the dignitaries** of the nascent counterculture*.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of The Grasshopper King.  Thanks for reading!  In that sentence, "dignitaries" is just a somewhat comic way of saying "notable figures."  So people like Gregory Corso would be dignitaries of the counterculture.  The "in" there is a preposition, just as you say:  if your restaurant had a lot of truckers for customers, you might say "my restaurant does a steady traffic in truckers."  But to be totally honest with you, I think the "in" reads a bit strangely there, and it might not have been the best choice.

Comment: Your book is amazing.